# My android phone is not sending signals to the arduino uno or maybe the arduino uno card is not communicating to the servo motor sg90

Tags: android, arduino, arduino-uno, android-studio-3.0, arduino-ide

I am uploading the code of both the android-studio as well as the arduino uno.. It seems right but somehow it doesn't work

Android Studio code :

```
package com.example.chintan.doorlock;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.os.Handler;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "00:21:13:01:ED:10"; //MAC Address of Bluetooth Module
private final UUID PORT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

private BluetoothDevice device;
private BluetoothSocket socket;

private OutputStream outputStream;
private InputStream inputStream;

Thread thread;
byte buffer[];

boolean stopThread;
boolean connected = false;
String command;

Button lock_state_btn, bluetooth_connect_btn;

TextView lock_state_text;

ImageView lock_state_img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lock_state_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lock_state_btn);
    bluetooth_connect_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_connect_btn);

    lock_state_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lock_state_text);

    lock_state_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lock_state_img);

    bluetooth_connect_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

           if(BTinit()) //initialises bluetooth
           {
               BTconnect(); //connects android code to arduino
               beginListenForData();


               // The code below sends the number 3 to the Arduino asking it to send the current state of the door lock so the lock state icon can be updated accordingly
               command = "3";

               try
               {
                   outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
               }
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }
       }
    });

    lock_state_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

        if(connected == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please establish a connection with the bluetooth servo door lock first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            command = "1";

            try
            {
                outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); // Sends the number 1 to the Arduino. For a detailed look at how the resulting command is handled, please see the Arduino Source Code
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

       }
    });
}

void beginListenForData() // begins listening for any incoming data from the Arduino
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    stopThread = false;
    buffer = new byte[1024];

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopThread)
            {
                try
                {
                    int byteCount = inputStream.available();

                    if(byteCount > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];
                        inputStream.read(rawBytes);
                        final String string = new String(rawBytes, "UTF-8");

                        handler.post(new Runnable()
                        {
                           public void run()
                           {
                                if(string.equals("3"))
                                {
                                    lock_state_text.setText("Lock State: LOCKED"); // Changes the lock state text
                                    lock_state_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.locked_icon); //Changes the lock state icon
                                }
                                else if(string.equals("4"))
                                {
                                    lock_state_text.setText("Lock State: UNLOCKED");
                                    lock_state_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlocked_icon);
                                }
                           }
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    stopThread = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}


@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
}
}
```

And this is my arduino source code :

```
 //Android-controlled Arduino Bluetooth Servo Door Lock by uscv

#include <Servo.h>

#include <EEPROM.h>

Servo servo;
char state;

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
  servo.attach(7);

  if(EEPROM.read(0) == 1) // Reads the EEPROM value stored to know what state the door lock was in before it was last turned off
  {                       // An EEPROM value of 1 means UNLOCKED and a value of 2 means LOCKED
servo.write(0); // Rotates the servo to the unlocked position
delay(200);
  }
  else if(EEPROM.read(0) == 2)
  {
    servo.write(75); // Rotates the servo to the locked position
    delay(200);
  }

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char data;
    data = Serial.read(); // The variable data is used to store the value sent by the Android app

switch(data)
{
  case '1': 
    if(EEPROM.read(0) == 1) //An EEPROM value of 1 means it is currently unlocked
    {
      EEPROM.write(0, 2); // Writes the number 2 to address 0 on the Arduino's EEPROM. This value will be used by the Arduino to remember the last state the door lock was in
      Serial.print("3"); // Sends the number 3 to the Android app. To see what this does, please see the Android Studio Project file


        servo.write(75);
        delay(15);

    }
    else if(EEPROM.read(0) == 2) //An EEPROM value of 2 means it i currently locked
    {
      EEPROM.write(0, 1); // Writes the number 1 to address 0 on the Arduino's EEPROM. This value will be used by the Arduino to remember the last state the door lock was in
      Serial.print("4"); // Sends the number 4 to the Android app. The number sent will be used by the app to update the locked/unlocked icon

        servo.write(0);
        delay(15);
    }
    break;
  case '3':
      if(EEPROM.read(0) == '1')
      {
        Serial.print("4");
        }

      else if(EEPROM.read(0) == '2')
      {
        Serial.print("3");
        }   
        break;
}
  }

 }
```

So, first the android app will start bluetooth, then connect to the arduino uno card and then perform the following functions:
1. "3" sent from android phone to arduino
2. received either "4" or "3" based on its status from arduino uno to android
3. Change the lock image on the android phone
4. send "1" from the android phone to the arduino
5. Change the status of the servo motor sg90 from its current position

Now, my android application is error-free and connects to the arduino uno and also is able to start the bluetooth of the phone. It establishes the connection but does not change the position of the servo motor sg90. I dont understand the problem what should we do?

Comment: Did you put anything into EEPROM at address 0? And `1` ≠ `'1'`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling EEPROM.read() before initializating the EEPROM. In other words for example in your setup() you are checking whether you EEPROM address 0 contains a certain value rather than initialization it with a certain value. Then
in your loop(), again you are checking whether EEPROM address contains a certain value before any value is written to the EEPROM and thus you will never reach the EEPROM write part because your if statements always returns false. So, start first by writing a value to EEPROM address 0.